# how do I read files with specific name in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I have a folder that contains text files with different names. I need to read all files that have a specific name for example `bitrate`. for this, I used the following code. but the returned list is empty, although I have files that contain the same structure in their names. what is the problem?

```
a=glob.glob("E:/data_from_twitch/Archive/qs_kk_v1_results_full_160p/asmr_1_0000/*bitrate.txt")
```

Comment: That will only find files whose name ends in `...bitrate.txt`.  If the "bitrate" part can occur elsewhere, use `"...0000/*bitrate*.txt"`.  Or, just fetch `*.txt` and do the filtering yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need double `**` (*glob operator*):

```
a=glob.glob("E:/data_from_twitch/Archive/qs_kk_v1_results_full_160p/asmr_1_0000/**/*bitrate.txt")
```

And probably you may need the argument `recursive=True`. See [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Comment: the name of files are like "asmr_1_0000_bitrate.txt" and the bitrate is at the end of the name. do I need to use **?

Comment: Yes, they are different things in this case. Have you tried this? It should work becase the `**` wil get you a list of files in that path and the `*` before `bitrate` will filter `asmr_1_0000_` or any other pattern.

Comment: Note that `**` are enclosed by *backslashes*: `/**/*bitrate.txt`, so the filtering of the name comes after that.

Comment: yes, I used it but the output list is empty although I have files with these names